# Tangent bundle of sphere with $g$ handles

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

How can one show that tangent bundle $TM$ is not trivial if $M$ is a sphere with $g$ handles and $g \ne 1$?

Comment: Do you know how to do this for $g=0$, i.e. the $2$-sphere?

Comment: @Dirk: How to answer this question depends largely on your background. Is that a homework/exam question for some course? What have you learnt?

Comment: It's was an exam question(with 2 stars:) ) in the course "Calculus on manifolds". I didn't solved it and didn't find any elementary solution.

Comment: Yes, I know the proof for the case $g$=0. I use the degree map and the fact that degree of antipodal map is $-1$. I don't know any analogue of antipodal map for $g$ more $1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The Poincaré–Hopf theorem

Comment: Can u give me a reference for the proof, please? It seems to be much more harder than this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite an elemental [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/609461/111377) of this fact, though you need some calculations.